# Subdownloader no longer working

Tags: video, vlc, software-installation, video-player

I've had this problem for a little while now: subdownloader no longer succeeds to download subtitles. It finds the subtitles fine, but fails to download them (there's no error message, the status just stays forever "downloading..." until I tell it to abort).

I know there's alternatives to this program (I've successfully installed extensions for SMplayer and VLC), but the convenient thing I like about subdownloader is that it can download several subtitles in one go (useful if you have a lot of videos to manage).

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is hear:

http://forum.opensubtitles.org/viewtopic.php?t=1303

"100 downloads for 12 hours per IP, there is no limit I think, but out search result is limited to 250 results"